# Skip for loop if file exists

Tags: python

I am processing some files from a folder that is being frequently updated. I need to add a piece of code that would check whether the file is already in a folder, and if not then go ahead with processing. If yes, then just skip and go for another one. So far I have this:

```
files_processed = os.listdir(path) # ['AZ_saturday_id-1', 'AZ_saturday_id-2', 'AZ_sunday_id-1', 'BY_saturday_id-1']

initials = ['AZ', 'BY', 'CX']
day = ['saturday', 'sunday']
id = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

files = []

for init in initials:
    for d in day:
        for i in id:
            name = f'{init}_{d}_id-{i}'

            if name in files_processed:
                continue
            
            files.append(name)
```

But this doesn't do what I would expect. The variable `files` gets all file names created in the for loop but it should have only the ones that do not exist in the `files_processed` yet.

When I try:

```
name in files_processed
```

that evaluates to True/False correctly but it doesn't work in the loop. Any ideas?

Comment: This is working fine on my end. Can you share the value of `files_processed` and of `files`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the os library, like so:

```
import os

os.path.exists("file.txt")
```

Or like this:

```
import os.path

if os.path.isfile('filename.txt'):
    print ("File exists")
else:
    print ("File does not exist")
```